# Find: Parameter format not correct

Tags: cygwin, find

I keep hearing this is a path issue with cygwin.  It is prevent emacs from working within my cygwin.  When I execute find on the cli (not bash/cygwin) I get the same error not matter what I type.  I've read this is a problem with path creation within cygwin and that it should be prepending itself to the path.  As you can see it is doing that.

Here is my /etc/profile

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that as everyone else stated, emacs is using find.exe provided by windows.  To change this, you need to change your %userprofile%.emacs file.

As nobody else states (even faq!), this file is not created automatically anymore.  Go into Options > Save options the mini-buffer (one line at the bottom of emacs) will tell you where the file is being written to.

Go in there and add this line (You've installed cygwin at c:\cygwin, right?):

```
(setq find-program "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\find.exe")
```

You may need to restart Emacs for this to take effect.

Comment: Or `"C:/cygwin/bin/find.exe"`.

Comment: If you use emacs-w32 (native Windows GUI), then "/usr/bin/find" is even nicer. This way you can put it to ~/.emacs and use this config without changes on both linux and cygwin.

Answer (score 9):

Just add this line to you **.profile**

**alias find='/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/find.exe'**

Answer (score 1):

Oddly-enough, I needed to use

```
(setq find-program "/bin/find.exe")
```

instead.

But thanks for the suggestion Drew.

Comment: Probably due to the need to double the backslashes.  I edited Drew's answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `setq find-program [msys2 or git path]` in my init file, as suggested (I tried different forms), didn't work for me. "C:\Windows\System32\find.exe" is first in the path if I type `where find` in eshell and I didn't find how to remove it, only how to add others, which doesn't solve the problem.

So I share here the more *radical*, but working (also in Powershell), solution I used: replacing the find.exe in "C:\Windows\System32" with the one from "C:\msys64\usr\bin". I kept the old file in case, but so far so good. You need to change the permissions for this operation (see [here](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/you-require-permission-from-trustedinstaller-error-fixing-guide/) how to gain full control, but I suggest only applying this to the file, not the whole folder, and putting things back after ;)).