# Running a shell script through Cygwin on Windows

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

I have a bunch of shell scripts that used to run on a Linux machine. Now, we've switched over to Windows, and I need to run these scripts there. I have [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) installed, but is there a way to make the script run using Cygwin, but the **call is made from Windows batch**?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Sure. On my (pretty vanilla) Cygwin setup, `bash` is in `c:\cygwin\bin` so I can run a `bash` script (say `testit.sh`) from a Windows batch file using a command like:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash testit.sh
```

... which can be included in a `.bat` file as easily as it can be typed at the command line, and with the same effect.

Comment: just a reminder:   set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH% && C:\cygwin64\bin\bash testit.sh

Comment: When i try this, I get errors from the shell scripts commands, "mkdir: command not found".  It seems like the shell script is being executed by Windows, not cygwin?

Comment: @swv: That is easy to test. For example, if you put `echo -n hello` in a script `testit.sh`, when run by Cygwin the output will be `hello` and when run by the Windows command interpreter the output will be `-n hello`. I expect a more likely explanation is that the path is not being set correctly in `bash`, so I would check to see if `bash` is reading `.profile` or `.bash_profile` correctly

Comment: Hey I am getting a "FIND: Parameter format not correct" .. its not recognizing bash commands? even though I can run it in cygwin...

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus: You may be using the Windows `find.exe` rather than the bash version - see [Find: Parameter format not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918341/find-parameter-format-not-correct), for example.

Comment: @user861746 I think your comment solves my old question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1602846/how-to-get-correct-environment-when-launching-cygwin-script

Comment: grep: command not found ... 
you *NEED* to manually put in your own script things like path 
but, yes, solution is working

Answer (score 48):

One more thing - if You edited the shell script in some Windows text editor, which produces the `\r\n` line-endings, cygwin's bash wouldn't accept those `\r`. Just run `dos2unix testit.sh` before executing the script:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\dos2unix testit.sh
C:\cygwin\bin\bash testit.sh
```

Answer (score 34):

If you have access to the Notepad++ editor on Windows there is a feature that allows you to easily get around this problem:

1. Open the file that's giving the error in Notepad++.
2. Go under the "Edit" Menu and choose "EOL Conversion"
3. There is an option there for "UNIX/OSX Format." Choose that option.
4. Re-save the file.

I did this and it solved my problems.

Hope this helps!

Read more at http://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/microsoft-windows-cygwin-error-r-command-not-found/

Comment: For Sublime Text users it's View->Line Endings->Unix

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add that you can do this to apply dos2unix fix for all files under a directory, as it saved me heaps of time when we had to 'fix' a bunch of our scripts.

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix.exe {} \;
```

I'd do it as a comment to Roman's answer, but I don't have access to commenting yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind always including .sh on the script file name, then you can keep the same script for Cygwin and Unix (Macbook).

To illustrate:
1. Always include .sh to your script file name, e.g., test1.sh
2. test1.sh looks like the following as an example:

    `#!/bin/bash
    echo '$0 = ' $0
    echo '$1 = ' $1
    filepath=$1`

3. On Windows with Cygwin, you type "test1.sh" to run
4. On a Unix, you also type "test1.sh" to run

Note: On Windows, you need to use the file explorer to do following once:
1. Open the file explorer
2. Right-click on a file with .sh extension, like test1.sh
3. Open with... -> Select sh.exe
After this, your Windows 10 remembers to execute all .sh files with sh.exe.

Note: Using this method, you do not need to prepend your script file name with bash to run

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers all seem to run this script in a DOS console window.

This may be acceptable, but for example means that colour codes (changing text colour) don't work but instead get printed out as they are:

> there is no item "[032mGroovy[0m"

I found this solution some time ago, so I'm not sure whether `mintty.exe` is a standard Cygwin utility or whether you have to run the `setup` program to get it, but I run like this:

```
D:\apps\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico  bash.exe .\myShellScript.sh
```

... this causes the script to run in a Cygwin BASH console instead of a Windows DOS console.