# how to run bash script from R

Tags: r, bash, shell

I have a bash script with name **test.sh** existed in the folder **c:/test**

**Problem Source:**

The mainly reason to run bash in r, actually I have .nc4 files download with r and i would like to get its bandinfo by using `gdalinfo` in r which was more easy work in bash than in r.  That why I have prepared another script in bash which can read these .nc4 files.

**Search before posting**

I search a function in r `system' but after setting path to the folder where my bash file exit i am trying this command in R

```
x <- "bash test.sh" #my bash file which i want to run in r
system(x, intern = TRUE,ignore.stdout = FALSE, ignore.stderr = FALSE, wait = TRUE, input = NULL, show.output.on.console = TRUE,minimized = FALSE, invisible = TRUE)
```

but getting this error

```
Error in system(x, intern = TRUE, ignore.stdout = FALSE, ignore.stderr = FALSE,  : 
  'bash' not found
```

**Acknowledgements**

highly thanks for resolving this problem. I am using Rstudio for the first.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  , the reason to use bash here actually its more easy in bash than r to get band by using gdalinfo. After getting my selective band from nc4 file i would like to crop this band with the help of my **shapefile** . Any easy approch u can guide me well dear? i have **ncdf4** package in r

Comment: For those searching for something similar and finding this question, post a new question with complete details since this has many in-R answers but there's little point in trying to tease out info comment-by-comment here.

Comment: It would seem `bash` is not in your PATH?

Comment: "I have a bash script with name test.sh existed in the folder **c:/test**" ... yeah, running a bash script ain't gonna work.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik dear , will you explain the `PATH` please. Is its meaning are path of my directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a bash script with name test.sh existed in the folder c:/test

You're using Windows, and bash scripts are meant for Unix/Linux. So that isn't going to work.

You have to install a bash shell to run bash scripts. You can try [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) for starters; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736898/running-a-shell-script-through-cygwin-on-windows) for an example question on running bash scripts in Cygwin. Alternatively, if you're on Windows 10 you can install the [bash for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/about) subsystem. In the latter case, your Windows filesystem can be accessed via `/mnt/<drive letter>`. So the script `c:\test\test.sh` would be `/mnt/c/test/test.sh`.

Comment: I am using Lunix commands on window using Cygwin and after setting its paths, I am calling it from **osgeo4w** .  _bash_ sccript is running finely on window. Dear i want to call a bash script which deals with the nc files ( a protion of my r code)  and i have to run this inside my for loop of r so that portion of my that code excute with bash.. **The problem is with the calling of bash file within rstudio, My question is about that**

Comment: I have ubuntu for windows, setting the path as I would on ubuntu still doesn't let me run the .sh script. Idk if there's a way to tell it it should run it from ubuntu? (still looking obv, this thread is old, but if u got anything let me know)